# PHP7 readfile() / file_get_contents() timeout

Tags: php, readfile

On server A I'm trying to `readfile()` (or `file_get_contents()`) an url which basically just echo's a line of text which should then be displayed. This basically works but on some "server B's" I get a pesky timeout and I cannot put my finger on why that is happening. The string is then not returned and a PHP warning thrown.

I've already checked for the necessary php.ini settings and basically `fopen()` wrappers and stuff should work, so I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you paste code?

Comment: if you are reading a file contents from a different server, you should use curl instead of file_get_contents(). By using `file_get_contents()` you rely on the servers timeout settings, which is not good, because it can be a pretty large number for a request (30s for example). By using curl, you can set the timeout on your own, have error reporting, etc.

Comment: Can you resolve the ip address of 'some server B' ... DNS fallback can be quite long on some installations.

Comment: IvanRubinson no, sorry, can't do that.
spielerds: thanks, I'll try to refactor my code
YvesLeBorg: sadly not, but thanks for the idea